# Where does a debian repo store its indicies?

Tags: debian

I accidentally deployed a package versioned to be 2.0 to our local repo, it should have been 1.0. I deleted the file of the repo but when a client tries to install the package it still tries to get 2.0. Is there somewhere in the repo machine that caches the latest version of all packages? how can I clear it?

Comment: While setting up a mirror before once, one file that looked amusing was `ls-Rl.gz` which could be part of it.  But I don't think that is all.  I'm not versed enough in mirror/repo mechanics to give you more than that.

Comment: There was a Packages.gz in the root of the repo that had the information. I deleted the old records from here.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Packages.gz file in the root of your repo and unzip. It will have a list of all packages this repo knows about and is the file downloaded by clients when the do apt-get update. Just remove entries for the packages that are causing problems.